# Does the stuffed armadillo in Obi-Wan Kenobi's hut belong to a missing species?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope, object-identification

At the beginning of *A New Hope*, we are introduced to the residence of old hermit Ben Kenobi: A synstone hut located at Tatooine’s Dune Sea.

Inside the hut we can see a lot of artifacts. Some of them probably belonged to former residents of this dwelling place, considering that for Obi-Wan, as a Jedi knight, attachments are forbidden.

In reference to these artifacts, Pablo Hidalgo (Lucafilm creative executive) and Leland Chee (Lucasfilm official) have mentioned/commented about the existence of a stuffed armadillo among the artifacts. If you have sharp eyes, you can get a glimpse of the stuffed armadillo (partial) on screen in the movie.

[image: Still Picture of A New Hope - Ben's hut with partial view of the stuffed armadillo]

I was looking around and found that there is a picture in Wookieepedia showing Ben Kenobi’s hut, wherein the stuffed armadillo can be seen on a display table.

[image: Wookieepedia Ben's Hut Interior]

https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/1/1b/BensHut_interior.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20071030213224

There is also a drawing of the same stuffed armadillo in the DK Star Wars Complete Locations.

[image: DK Star Wars Complete Locations Ben's Hut]

Regarding the armadillo as a species, the only entry of it in Wookieepedia is The Armored Krakkiss, a giant, beige-colored armadillo-like creature native to Tatooine. Obviously, given its size, this couldn’t be the stuffed armadillo in question, so, I wonder if this stuffed armadillo in old Ben’s hut is a missing species in the Star Wars Universe.

Pablo Hidalgo: Harmy's STAR WARS Despecialized Edition HD - 2004 feature-length audio commentary by Pablo Hidalgo for Star Wars Episode IV A New Hope.

Leland Chee: [Twitter 2013](https://twitter.com/HolocronKeeper/status/392499963302662144).

[image]

Comment: A baby Krakkiss?

Comment: Most stuffed elephants here on Earth are nowhere near real size.

Comment: looking at the simplified version in the lower section, it is labeled as an 'artefact', so it could be a stone statue in universe, or the creatures that evolved into the Krakkiss were smaller in pre-history.

Comment: @shufly - I think bingo is asking about the stuffed animal from the taxidermy pov.

Comment: @Palliser that is what the second part of my comment was referring to. The post says the armadillo never appeared on screen, so i figured the book is the 'more official' source for it existing in-universe. though i am not certain what is meant by 'missing species'.  Does it mean a species that we don't have a name for out of universe, a species that went extinct in universe?